# AngularJS Services : retrieve data from .asmx webservice using $http get with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, web-services, asmx

I have found tutorials how to use AngularJS $http get to retrieve data but could not find how to retrieve data from .asmx webservice using $http get with parameters.

In my AngularJS Services, I have the following code:

```
 .factory('BoothDesignatedCoordsService', ['$http', function ($http) {
 return {
    // Might retrieved from db eventually
    fnGetBoothDesignatedCoords: function (strBoothName, intFloorPlanID) {
        var boothDesignatedCoords
        strBoothName = "B29"
        intFloorPlanID = 3;
        var sendToWS;
        try {
            var JSONObj = {
                BoothName: strBoothName,
                FloorPlanID: intFloorPlanID
            };
            sendToWS = JSON.stringify(JSONObj)
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("error from fnGetBoothDesignatedCoords " + e)
        }

        try {
            var url = "http://localhost:4951/wsIPS.asmx/fnGetBoothDesignatedCoords";

            $http.get(url)
                  .success(function (data) {
                      var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                       boothDesignatedCoords = JSON.parse(jsonData);
                      alert("success");

                  })

        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("error from fnGetBoothDesignatedCoords2 " + e)
        }

        return boothDesignatedCoords;

    }

}
 }])
```

Can someone tell me where should I put the parameters (use the variable "sendToWS") to pass in? And any code missing? Thanks!

Comment: Ref : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http and check config

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$http({
    url: url, 
    method: "GET",
    params: { sendToWS: ... }
 });
```